# Shouldn't steam be compressed water in SAGD?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am doing some labor work on a rig and am confused about something. I heard from my superiors that we are injecting steam at 180°C with the wellbore pressure being 2 MPa. If I look at these conditions on a steam table, shouldn't the steam be compressed water?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, that water at 180°C and 2 MPa will be a liquid.

Perhaps the steam is not being injected at the "wellbore pressure", or its temperature rises during the injection process?

[image: Water Phase Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Most SAGD facilities inject steam at much higher temperatures and pressures (often over 300°C).  Downhole temperatures may be 180°C at 2 MPa.